# Port forwarding

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a local machine which has SSH access to **Server1**. **Server1** has access to **Server2** with Tomcat running on port 5050.  How can I can connect to that Tomcat on port 5050 on my local machine in the browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ssh -L <localport>:<server2>:<server2-port> user@host

Example: ssh -L 5050:server2.company.com:5050 user@host
```

Add **-f** to let the ssh session run in the background.

Add **-g** to let other hosts connect to server1s locally forwarded port.